# could not guess version control system

Tags: apache-flex, svn

recently, i upgraded to Flex Hero 4.5 and created a new workspace. Then, i imported a project from the former workspace and started working. when i tried to upload the  project from the new workspace to codereview, i got the error message: could not guess version control system. Are you in a working copy directory? How does one resolve this issue?
thanks
I have read somewhere that i need to checkout my svn but i thought that you only checkout when you want to get a folder/file from the svn.

Comment: ok here is what i need: i have just created a new workspace and i exported a project into this workspace but the .svn directory is missing in that workspace. As such, the svn version control is missing. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your latest comment, you did a `svn export` on your code. [The `export` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html), as the doc mentions, creates a "clean" directory tree, i.e. without the .svn directory. So basically, these are files not controlled by SVN; also, you lose all the history of your files. The best way would have been, I think, to do a checkout in your new workspace and then work from there. It could take some time, but it's much easier to manage afterwards.

One possible way to make this work would be to checkout a clean copy your code somewhere safe and then merge your changes into this clean copy. However, if your trunk or branch changed a lot in the meantime, this could be very, very tedious. I could then suggest to branch your trunk, checkout that new branch, slowly merge your changes into that branch and when you're done and everything's working OK, merge the branch back into the trunk.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you've got a bit of a mess unfortunately.  Hopefully you're not in the habit of doing a ton of changes without checking in.  I would suggest you:

- Back up your latest changes to a safe location
- Check out the project from SVN into your new workspace (which is what you should have done initially) - creating a **brand new** project folder
- Merge the changes you've made into the now-correctly-versioned copy of your project (you could do this by just copying files from the "latest"/project backup folder overwriting the SVN versioned files, but if you do--do NOT overwrite any .svn folders). You could also use a tool such as WinMerge or WinDiff to find differences between the two projects (of course ignoring .svn folders).

If you have a small number of changes it shouldn't be bad, but if there's a lot, you might want to follow SolarBear's branch suggestion, if WinMerge isn't going to cut it.